# spring security problems with the configuration my code and method are outmoded

Tags: spring

spring code

[image]

it is telling my spring security configuration is outmoded. Anyone to help me with the configuration of the new updated method.

I am new to spring.

Comment: Please don't post code as images or worse links as images. Also what is outmoded? I assume outdated? Looks like you are trying to follow some tutorial and decided to use newer versions instead of sticking with the versions mentioned in the tutorial/guide. Anyway the javadoc of the methods will tell you **exactly** what is the replacement.

Comment: okay thanks. but what do you think I should do? Because it's been weeks now

Comment: As stated, the documentation explains **exactly** what you need to do. Check the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeHttpRequests()) for the deprecated methods. Read that and update your configuration (that shouldn't be that hard to figure out).